# Batch executing a file and continuing to run

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7, vbscript, message

I have this code:

```
@echo off
Taskkill /f /im wscript.exe 2>> Log.txt 
If exist "%Temp%\done.vbs" (
 Attrib -R -S -H "%Temp%\done.vbs"
 del /F /Q "%Temp%\done.vbs"
 If exist "%Temp%\done.vbs" (
  Echo Could not delete file "%Temp%\done.vbs"
  Pause
 )
)
> "%Temp%\done.vbs" ECHO x=msgbox("stage 1" ,6, "Chip-set")
"%Temp%\done.vbs" 
DEL "%Temp%\done.vbs"
echo done
```

The code creates a message box. The problem with the code is that it pauses when the message box is open so it pauses the script. how do I make it continue to run the code even when the  message box is open. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
start "" wscript "%temp%\done.vbs"
```